# vuejs render part of template inside different elements without repeating

Tags: vuejs2, conditional-rendering

I am new to Vuejs. This is what I need to do.

```
<div v-for="r in records">
    <div v-if="r.something">
        <div id="x">
            {{ r. something}}
            more of r here.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div v-else id="x">
        same div as in the block above.
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want do is not define div with id x two times as it is huge.

Answer (score 2):

Make your 'div' a component and refer to it in both places.

There are many ways to define your component.  This is example shows just one.  If you are using WebPack, use a single file component.  You can then have your script, html, and css all in one file that gets precompiled.  That's the best way to manage your 'huge' div.  Then you can continue to refactor and break it up into more components.

```js
const myComponent = {
  template: "<div :id='id'>HELLO, my id is {{id}}. r.foo is {{r.foo}} </div>",
  props: {
    id: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      r: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-for="r in records">
  <div v-if="r.something">
    <my-component id='x' />
  </div>

  <div v-else id="x">
    <my-component id='x' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Just to get this done quickly, can you also tell me how can I pass `r` to the new component for accessing things inside `r` like doing `{{ r.something }}` inside the component ?

Comment: Add another prop to the component.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html.  Same way I feed 'id' into it.  Or declare it in data of component.  I'll update answer.

Comment: @AbbasFaisal please accept answer if it works for you.  Thanks!